# Uml Standard for "events" or "state"

Tags: uml

I'm trying to create some UML models, but i can't seem to find some official documentation, or a single answer for this issue, so i hope somebody can point my in the right direction.

For a UML diagram with a certain "event" or "state" meaning is there a standard model, that should be used?

an example could be

```
User creates request -> Request is processed -> Event is created (what figure should be used for this)
```

Is there a standard for these models?

Comment: Are you wanting to model behaviour or structure? State and events can be modeled in many ways depending on your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [UML specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/) and more specifically to the Activity or StateMachine sections.

Cheers,
EBR